# Async requests to a web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, web-services

How to make async requests to a webservice from a Thread?

Comment: In response to your first point, if you use a Silverlight Enabled WCF Service, silverlight will automatically generate the Async code for you e.g. a GetData() method on the service will generate GetDataCompleted and GetDataAsync methods on the client side for you to use.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it on a separate thread to prevent UI from hanging when user tries to do some other thing in the UI.

Comment: All code runs in __a__ thread but I suspect you mean you want ot make async requests in a thread that isn't the UI thread correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the short answer without a load of explanations.

Before calling the `Async` method on your Client object make sure you are not running on the UI Thread:-

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( o =>
{
   try
   {
      svc.SomeMethodAsync();
   }
   catch (err)
   {
       // do something sensible with err
   }
});
```

Now the corresponding completed event will occur on a `ThreadPool` thread not the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using WCF.

**Service Code FileService.svc**

```
public class FileService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
    {
        byte[] File;
        //do logic

        return File;
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
public int requested_file_count = 5;
public list<string> filenames;

public FileServiceClient svc 

//Constructor
public Example()
{
   svc = new FileServiceClient();
} 

Public void GetFiles()
{
    //Initialise the list of names and set the count of files received     
    filenames = new list<string>(5);
    requested_file_count = filenames.Count; 

   svc.GetFileCompleted += new EventHandler<GetFileCompletedEventArgs>(GetFile_Completed);

   //Call the Async Method passing it the file name and setting the userstate to 1;

   svc.GetFileAsync(filenames[0],1);
}

void GetFile_Completed(object Sender, GetFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.UserState == requested_file_count)
   {
     //All files have been downloaded
   }
   else
   {
      svc.GetFileAsync(filenames[e.UserState],++e.UserState);
   }

   //Do Something with the downloaded file
   byte[] filedata = e.result;
}
```

Comment: I am doing something like this. But I need to do it on a separate Thread

Comment: The async requests to webservice and updating the data structure should happen in a separate thread. Any idea how to do it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the service calls are running in a separate thread.