# How to async request to a sync API?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, api

I have built a REST API in Python using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Authlib](https://authlib.org) ([Oauth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) framework).

[image]

This API runs over a [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) container which I have configured the SSL, CORS, permanent session ...

When I try to request a token on the API using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in a [React](https://reactjs.org/) application, it works:

```
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `.../user/login`,
      data: {username, password}
    }).then(response => {
      ...
    }).catch(error => {
      ...
    })
```

But when I try to revoke this token making a Axios request to the logout middleware endpoint I receive `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403` ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzrLn.jpg)):

[image]

```
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `.../user/logout`,
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.login.access_token}`},
  }).then(response => {
    ...
  }).catch({
    ...
  })
```

I don't understand it. If I issue a token and revoke using a application like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Insonia](https://insomnia.rest/), it works.

How can I fix it ? Why is it happening ?

I research and found some threads, but I still have this issue: [Async requests to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824112/async-requests-to-a-web-service), [Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/893) ...

**Obs** ¹: I can't show the API source code for legal reasons with my employer

**Obs** ²: I'm assuming it's a async / sync problem, I not 100% sure

Comment: What does postman show?

Comment: `I'm assuming it's a async / sync problem` be assured, it as nothing to do with that ... the server understands the request but refuses to fulfil it - please check the browser developer tools network tab, specifically what headers are being sent and received for the `logout` request - and check for an OPTIONS preflight request that is triggered by the `Authorization` request header, what response does that have in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you get a Forbidden 403 response when you lack permissions to make the request. I think this has something to do with CORS. Can you please check the Network tab in your browser to make sure both the requests you make (through Postman and in the browser) look the same and if there's a OPTIONS request, what's the response?